# SSL Socket exception in android 5.0

Tags: android, apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am having issue with `Android L 5.0` when I use Https while API call. I am getting following **exception.**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLNullSession.getPeerCertificates(SSLNullSession.java:104)
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:388)
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:231)
11-26 15:35:01.919: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:302)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.layerProtocol(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:146)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:654)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:370)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
11-26 15:35:01.920: W/System.err(353):  at com.praxify.model.CallServer.makeHttpGetRequest(CallServer.java:1515)
```

Comment: Please put the log in a code block so the text does not wrap. (Add some spaces at start of first log line).

Comment: thanks Andres Cardenas Pardo

Comment: I am having the same error, but thats not Android 5 specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been dealing with this problem for a couple of days too, and finally i found the problem here, (but not excatly the solution). The thing is that since android 5, google does not trust SHA1 certificates that expires after 2016 (you can check if this is your situation connecting through a browser and looking at the lock). 
For me, the only thing we could do was to **ask for a new server certificate with SHA256** or SHA1 cert. with an expiring date in 2015. 
Sorry about my english

This discussion was also made here: https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1200

Answer (score 0):

After finding couple of days i came across to volley lib for API calls which helps us solve this issue, you may refer volley lib for handling  API calls. Volley lib works for me.

Find another [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=79089).

Lollpop: In-app billing broken because SHA1 fingerprint calculated from APK certificate differs from SHA1 in Developer Console and KitKat

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me the problem was because the server was using DES-CBC3-SHA cipher and in Android 5.0 the support for it is no longer enabled by default. More info about that here: https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html

So the solution for this problem is:
a) Change the server configuration so the server supports some of the more modern ciphers (it was not disabled for no reason).
b) Enable support for the cipher.

To check what cipher the server you can use:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.myurl.com:443
```

Hope this helps someone.